# Magento2: Order status issue

Tags: magento2, sales-order, order-status

I have created new order status "Test" from admin panel.

Status is not showing on sales order.

How can i show status on sales order?

Comment: Are you saying it's not showing in `sales grid`?

Comment: Yes, right @AdarshKhatri

Comment: I have created status 'test' and assign to state pending.  @AdarshKhatri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two different concepts: statuses and states.

Status is simply a label for humans. State determines the behaviour of the order in Magento. You usually have four important states: Pending, Processing, Completed and Closed. Within each of these states, you can have one or multiple statusses.

First, you need to create the status (which you've already done).

Then, you'll need to assign that status to an order state. Click the "Assign Status to State" button and choose "Processing" as the state, for example.

Now, when your order is in the processing state (when either an invoice or shipment exists, but not both), you have the option to change the status on the order page:

[image: choose order status]

Comment: Can you let me know this process please check the screenshot https://ibb.co/6BcM6KL

Comment: @MasudShaikh out of the box you can't change status from the order grid. You need to purchase a third party module for that. You can change status for each order by clicking into it.

Comment: Ok, can you share the link 3rd party module.

Comment: @MasudShaikh for example https://amasty.com/mass-order-actions-for-magento-2.html